# Do Cleric's domain spells add slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, spell-slots, domains

I'm a little bit confused with the whole spell system and additions to them.
If I pick for instance Tempest Domain Spell, are the spells additional to the other ones? (2 at level 1) So do that make it 3 spells? Does the domain add slots too?

And also, I've read about people choosing multiple domains, is that possible?

Answer (score 35):

The domain spells do not count against your number of prepared spells per day; they are extra, and always prepared (*PHB*, p. 58):

> Once you gain a domain spell, you always have it prepared, and it doesn't count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.

You still cast them as normal, spending a spell slot. **Divine Domain** only gives you more spells to choose from, but no extra spell slots for casting them.

You choose only one domain when you get the **Divine Domain** class feature at 1st level, as it instructs (*q.v.*):

> Choose one domain related to your deity

The people talking about choosing multiple domains are probably confused and misreading the advancement table and feature description. **Divine Domain feature** is listed as gained at multiple levels, but its description only lets you choose a domain when you get it at 1st level. The rest of the listings on the table are when its other benefits are gained (*q.v.*):

> Your choice grants you domain spells and other features **when you choose it at 1st level**. It also grants you additional ways to use Channel Divinity **when you gain that feature at 2nd level**, and additional benefits **at 6th, 8th, and 17th levels**.

Answer (score 3):

So, just to clarify:

- These spells do not add spell *slots*
- They *do* add to the spells known
- They *do not* count against prepared spells
- They *are always* prepared

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here. This answer is correct, but it could benefit from citing some rules to back up your answer. Also, answers here are expected to stand up by themselves rather than act as replies to other answers, so rather than saying "just to clarify" (which makes this seem like it's adding to another answer), make your answer stand up by itself as though it was the first answer posted so far.

Comment: Also, if I'm being pedantic, strictly speaking clerics don't have "spells known" since clerics know all of their spells.